# merging child table details with parent table details in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a query like below

```
$product = Customer::with('packages')
            ->find($id);
```

Where i can get package details as $product->packages;

One of the field of the packages is package_name and i can access it's value as 
`$product->packages->package_name` and it's working fine.

Is there anyway to merge $product->packages with $product, so that i can access the package name as `$product->package_name?`

Comment: What type of relation is `packages()`? If packages are an array, then you have a bit of a logic problem there. There might be 0 to multiple packages and you have to decide which one to show.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).

In your `Customer` Model add accessor.

```
public function getPackageNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->packages()->package_name;
    }
```

Now you can access directly using.

```
$product->package_name
```

Comment: `$this->packages()` will return a query builder, which doesn't have a property `package_name`.